# In php namespaces do I need to require each file

Tags: php, namespaces

If I'm using namespace and for example I have the following directory tree

```
Test/someclass.php

Test/someotherclass.php
```

can I simply do

```
use \Test\someotherclass
```

or I need first to do

```
require 'Test/someotherclass.php'
```

and then I can actually use that class
because currently when I do that I get the following error

> Fatal error: Class 'Test\someOtherClass' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Test\someClass.php on line 10

Comment: Namespaces !== autoloader..... use an autoloader to include class files as they are required

Comment: [PHP DOC](http://us3.php.net/manual/fr/function.spl-autoload-register.php) have a look at this

Comment: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/ and https://gist.github.com/jwage/221634

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments the `namespace` and the `use` statement don't load anything by default.
But you can use an [autoloader](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) based on namespace. You have a standard called [psr-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) for autoload.